# removing data from txt file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have a comma-delimited giant file that was exported from a database. The file has this format

```
Date,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,color,type,reference
10-Jan-2000,344,13,21,2,55,3,"rose garden" ,3444,32
11-Jan-2000,324,3,1,21,5,23,"space green fox" ,3444,11
12-Jan-2000,34,23,31,22,5,34,"bourbon mars" ,3444,88
```

Notice that the color field is surrounded by quotes and has a space at the end. Don't ask me why.

I would like to end with a file that is just this:

```
n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6
344,13,21,2,55,3
324,3,1,21,5,23
34,23,31,22,5,34
```

what magic command should I type on terminal to get rid of the date, color, type and reference on all lines of that txt file?

Comment: `cut -d, -f2-7`

Comment: man, I love you. You are a genius!!!!! Please add this comment as an answer!

Comment: FYI, the format is called CSV (Comma Separated Values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cut -d, -f 2-7 filename
```

or

```
awk -F, '{OFS=","; print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' filename
```